# Get window inner width and height of android built in webbrowser at all zoom levels

Tags: android, browser, height, width, zooming

I am trying by using javascript to get the window width and height of the build in webbrowser but can't find the right method, currently it seems the DOM doesn't know about the zoom level changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can try to do this :

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

metrics.width is the screen's wide 
metrics.height is the screen's height